# pow and lround (from math.h) not working in solaris

Tags: c, solaris

I am writing and implementation of the Miller-Rabin primality test. I believe I have implemented it correctly, but I cannot get my C code to compile on solaris. The code compiles fine in OS X and Debian, but I am getting linking errors in solaris. When I try to link my program, I get the following errors:

```
gcc -Wall prime.o -o prime
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
pow                                 prime.o
lround                              prime.o
```

I am include stdio.h, stdlib.h, and math.h. Does anyone know what the problem could be? I know that in solaris you sometimes need to link against addition libraries, could this be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to link with the `-lm`. Try:

```
gcc -Wall prime.o -o prime -lm
```

There's also a [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/fp/libm.html) about this.

Answer (score 1):

Link with math library using -lm flag

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out. I needed to link with `-lm`.

Comment: Max, please refrain from inflamatory language. This is not constructive. I flagged this answer.

Comment: Don't know if this needs to be flagged but Solaris is really a beautiful OS.

Comment: Solaris is no different than any other Unix or Linux OS here - you have to specify the libraries that define functions on all of them, the compiler won't go hunting them down for you.